# Inherit class with weakref in slots

Tags: python, inheritance, weak-references

I tried to use weak references on my classes, where I use slots to save some memory, but I wasn't able to make derived class.

```
class A(object):
    __slots__ = ['__weakref__']

class B(A):
    __slots__ = A.__slots__ + ['foo']
#TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
#    __weakref__ slot disallowed: either we already got one, or __itemsize__ != 0
```

Where's the trick? I didn't find any solution. I'm using python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In derived classes you should *not* put slots that were defined in the base classes.

In fact the error says:

> `TypeError`: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       `__weakref__` slot disallowed: either **we already got one**, or `__itemsize__ != 0`

Simply use:

```
class B(A):
    __slots__ = ['foo']
```

This is explained in the documentation for[`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> The action of a `__slots__` declaration is limited to the class where it
>   is defined. As a result, subclasses will have a `__dict__` unless they
>   also define `__slots__` (*which must only contain names of any **additional**
>   slots*).

Comment: Thanks, that was it. How to handle slots in derived class is somewhat hidden in documentation, so I didn't found it.